# Later Date in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to convert in Swift 3 syntax. In which we check startdate is later date.

```
 while (startDate.laterDate(endDate) != startDate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a wild guess as to what you want, since you weren't very clear. Does this do what you want?

```
while (startDate < endDate) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Extension for Swift 3/4:

### Silly Version

```
extension Date {
    func later(_ otherDate: Date) -> Date {
        return (self as NSDate).laterDate(otherDate)
    }
}
```

### Slightly Less Silly Version (or More Silly?)

```
extension Date {
    func later(_ otherDate: Date) -> Date {
        switch self.compare(otherDate) {
        case .orderedAscending:
            return otherDate
        default:
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible replacement of `dateA.laterDate(dateB)` is:

```
max(dateA, dateB)
```

In your case, since you're comparing the result to one of the two components, then a direct comparison is enough:

```
while startDate < endDate {
```